# Materialized view not working as expected?

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple query:

```
select * from tags where tags.taggable_type = 'Skill';
```

It takes roughly:

```
Seq Scan on tags  (cost=0.00..378.81 rows=11775 width=77) (actual time=0.019..7.092 rows=11775 loops=1)
  Filter: ((taggable_type)::text = 'Skill'::text)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 4610
  Planning time: 0.098 ms
  Execution time: 8.536 ms
(5 rows)
```

To retrieve these records. I created a materialized view in hopes that the time to retrieve would reduce drastically but in reality I got this when running the mat query:

```
explain analyze select * from skill_matview;

Seq Scan on skill_matview  (cost=0.00..239.75 rows=11775 width=76) (actual time=0.078..5.481 rows=11775 loops=1)
   Planning time: 1.562 ms
   Execution time: 6.900 ms
(3 rows)
```

Am I missing something, I keep looking around and everything is boasting some pretty good query reduction times but I'm not seeing that here.

Edit:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW skill_matview AS select * from tags where tags.taggable_type = 'Skill';
```

Comment: you could add how you created a materialyzed view

Comment: edited the post on how I create the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much to gain with a materialized view in your case.

The original query has to scan the whole 16385 rows, and the `WHERE` condition removes only 4610 of them.

So the materialized view will be about three quarters as big as the table, and a sequential scan of it will take about three quarters the time, which is roughly in line with what you observe.

Besides, 9 milliseconds isn't so bad, is it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any other way that I would be able to reduce that query time?

Comment: 11K rows in 7ms, and you still want to speed it up? Maybe change your data model in such a way that you do not *need* to retrieve 11K records.

Comment: @Rogue Below 6.900 ms? I highly doubt that. You could always upgrade your hardware, but you'll never outrun a sequential scan when "all" rows are needed. Are you sure you need every *11775* row at once?

Comment: I'm quite sure I don't need every 11775 row at once but the front end for this is a bag of shit which is making this difficult ;(